# How to download YouTube videos?

Tags: downloads, youtube

There is any good program to download YouTube videos? I am using Ubuntu 14.04 32-bit.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**To install `youtube-dl`**:

- Recommended way (latest version):

  1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or searching **Terminal** in the dash.
  2. Install `youtube-dl` with this command (you'll be prompted for your password):

     ```
     sudo wget https://yt-dl.org/downloads/latest/youtube-dl -O /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl && sudo chmod a+x /usr/local/bin/youtube-dl
     ```
- Not recommended way (older version):

  1. Open a terminal with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> or searching **Terminal** in the dash.
  2. Install `youtube-dl` with this command (you'll be prompted for your password):

     ```
     sudo apt-get install youtube-dl
     ```

---

**To use `youtube-dl`:**

1. To select where to save the video, you can follow these steps:

   - Type `cd` on the terminal.
   - Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
   - Drag the folder from File Manager and drop it on the terminal.
   - If you skip this step, the video will be saved on your home folder.
2. To download the video you can use one of these procedures:

   2.1. Run `youtube-dl video_url` where `video_url` is the URL of the video.

   2.2. If you want to download many videos, you can follow these steps instead of 2.1:

   - Run the below command:

     ```
     xargs youtube-dl
     ```
   - Repeat the following procedure for each link:

     - Paste a link.
     - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
   - Press <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>D</kbd>

   2.3. If do you have a plain text file with a list of links, you can download them this way:

   - Type `cat` on the terminal.
   - Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
   - Drag the file form the File Manager and drop it on the terminal.
   - Press <kbd>Space</kbd>
   - Type `| xargs youtube-dl`
   - Press <kbd>Enter</kbd>
3. Now the video(s) will download to the selected folder.

---

**Some final thoughts:**

- On the method 2.3 the final command should look like this:

  ```
  cat '/home/foo/Desktop/myawesomevideos.txt' | xargs youtube-dl
  ```
- You can also use the URL of a channel and `youtube-dl` will save the entire channel.
- You can update `youtube-dl` with `sudo youtube-dl -U`
- You can see all the options of `youtube-dl` with `youtube-dl --help`

---

**Thanks to [user185719](https://askubuntu.com/users/185719) and [Michael Grünewald](https://askubuntu.com/users/393291) for their contributions to this answer.**

Comment: You should download it  directly from the website instead from the repository because that's a outdated version.
http://rg3.github.io/youtube-dl/download.html

Follow the 2 commands given there.

Comment: Most of the time, video URLs contain strange characters like `?` which must be escaped. It much easier to use `xargs youtube-dl` which allows to paste several URLs in the terminal and saves from adding single quotes around them.

Comment: @user185719: I updated the answer. Thanks.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald: There is no need to escape `?` or any other sign (at least on my computer ;-). However, the `xargs` solution is good.

Comment: @Helio It depends on your shell. The `?` is a wildcard character that can be used to write globbing patterns, and the `?` will match any character. When there is no match, some shells use the globbing pattern as an argument, some other shells signal an error. On these shells, the `?` must be protected and the `xargs` trick is even more useful.

Comment: @MichaelGrünewald: Ok, however, nowadays, in all the currently supported ubuntu versions the default shell is `bash` ***;-)***. However, I updated my answer to include your solution.

Answer (score 2):

You can use firefox as the browser and there are some addons which will enable you to download videos from youtube like [this](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-us/firefox/addon/easy-youtube-video-download/)

Comment: +1: Easy solution for newbies (i.e. The OP). However, youtube-dl is better.

Answer (score -3):

simply open an additional tab in the same browser and search for savefrom.net and open the website.
Now open the youtube video and copy the URL when it starts playing.
Paste that in the space given for URL in the savefrom.net website.

Comment: yes it's possible and working but why doing this if you can just simply add an add-on savefrom.net and download it right away.